# Unable to resolve module ./list/ListItem from E:\socal project\social-app\node_modules\react-native-elements\dist\index.js:

Tags: reactjs, react-navigation, react-native-elements

[I'm facing the error while using the react-native-elements (search bar)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M61st.png)

Comment: could you please paste the code page that's showing this error?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your folder structure, it looks like you want to import `ListItem` from `"./List"`.

You can learn more about the different types of imports on the React website: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/importing-a-component